# Bidding System PHP-MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on the bidding system app, stuck on how to select the appropriate data and display. See the table screenshot. What I trying to retrieve is for example for bid_id p1 I want latest fbid,name, total amount of all 3 records having bid_id=p1.
[image]

```
$check = "SELECT * FROM bid_info WHERE bid_id = '$bid_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: What if you receive comma separated `fbid` and `name`

Comment: You have 3 records with `bid_id=p1`, but you're limiting your results to one record. How can you get the total of all three?

Comment: I just want to add the amount of all 3 records

Comment: Then you need to get all 3. Your SQL query limits you to only 1 record... the one with `id = 3` because you're going in descending order of the `id` field.

Comment: To be precise sum(amount) and latest id,name which I try to achieve through ORDER by id DESC,

Comment: Using this query, SELECT sum(amount), name FROM bid_info WHERE bid_id = 'p1' ORDER BY id DESC. returning correct amount but wrong name, It should return the id 3 i-e Test Name3

Comment: What name are you getting?

Comment: Another big question is why do you have 3 different people using the same `bid_id`?

Comment: bid_id is same(its product id), but fbid is different for all

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the query you are looking for...

```
$check = "SELECT * FROM bid_info WHERE bid_id = '$bid_id'"
$result = mysql_query($check);

$total= 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$total += $row['bid_id'];
}
```

Also, you should be using pdo_mysql instead of mysql. mysql has been deprecated eons ago and will soon stop functioning. Then all of your code will stop functioning.

**Reference**

[pdo_mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: but what about the name,fbid i-e of id 3